# Speedometer and Odometer not reading, bad fuel consumption

Tags: toyota, fuel-consumption, speedometer, rav4, odometer

I have a 1995 model Toyota RAV4 automatic transmission. The speedometer and Odometer sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. What could be the problem causing this erratic behaviour.

The same car consumes much fuel per kilometer (1 liter for 7 Kilometers). What could be the problem behind this terrible fuel consumption?

Also when changing gear to reverse there is a there is knocking sound.

May i have answers for for these problems please.

Dare-es-Salaam, Tanzania

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: When was it last properly serviced? Also check for loose connections.

Comment: Any transmission codes in the computer? Sounds like the speed sensor in the trans is failing, but should set a code if it is.

Comment: If the consumption meter works off the same signal as the speedo and odo, then you have used a lot of fuel to go (apparently) not very far, which would account for the bad consumption.